# Flutter title displace for leading icon

Tags: flutter, dart

When I used icon on leading, flutter title shift right side, why it is not in same place. Is there any other way to make the title in the middle of appbar.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63804372/back-button-displaced-title-of-appbar/63804435#63804435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `centerTitle: true` to make the title center of appBar.

```
AppBar(
  centerTitle: true, // this is all you need
  //Rest Code here
)
```